# OpenCV density of feature points

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, feature-detection

Using OpenCV SIFT algorithm i am able to get the matching and non matching feature points between 2 images. My solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775842/opencv-draw-non-matching-points/43782475#43782475)
The distribution of matched(green) and non-matched(red) feature points is as shown below.(i cant reveal the actual image. but the image contains mostly text)
[image]
I want to calculate a density function for the matching and non matching points on an image(i.e. given a nXn area on the image, density function should give how many matching points are present inside this nXn area). How can i do that?

Secondly, i want to calculate a function that gives ratio of densities of matching and non-matching feature points inside a nXn area on the image.
I am using Python code on Windows 7 and build from latest OpenCV source.

Comment: Can you post an image of the matching and non-matching feature points to better understand their distribution?

Comment: @ElouarnLaine check the image

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not, could you explain why so I can improve my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the **densities** of *matching* and *non-matching keypoints* you could divide your image in sub-squares of a given size and calculate the two densities on each square. See the example below:

[image: local densities on a given square]
This would allow to **discretize** the densities on surfaces of the same area. To calculate the densities of a given square, you can do the following:

- Create a [Rect](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html)*(x ,y, width, height)* object corresponding to the square.
- Loop over all the *non-matching keypoints* and check how many of them are **contained** in the Rect (you can use Rect.[contains](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#a66b63fc11cc3872ff2dad2603278e10e)*(Point)*).
- Repeat the previous step for the *matching keypoints*.
- Compute the densities (*Keypoints per square pixel*) like shown in my example picture.

**N.B.** Actually, *Rect* only exists in **OpenCV C++**, so you can re-create a *Rect* (and its *contains* method) class in Python if you want (it is not required though).